# BeatifulSoup struggling to scrape the Listings Detail Page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm still a rookie on the Python world. I'm trying to build a **scraper** that will be useful on my daily work routine. But I'm stuck at a particular point:

My goal is to scrape a real estate website. I'm using BeatifulSoup, and I manage to get the parameters on the lists pages without problems. But when I enter on the listing details page, I'm not managing to **scrape** any data.

My code:

```html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://timetochoose.co.ao/?search-listings=true"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'whatever'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response)

data = response.text

print(data)

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

anuncios = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "grid-listing-info"})

for anuncios in anuncios:
    titles = anuncios.find("a",{"class": "listing-link"}).text
    location = anuncios.find("p",{"class": "location muted marB0"}).text
    link = anuncios.find("a",{"class": "listing-link"}).get("href")
    anuncios_response = requests.get(link)
    anuncios_data = anuncios_response.text
    anuncios_soup = BeautifulSoup(anuncios_data, 'html.parser')
    conteudo = anuncios_soup.find("div", {"id":"listing-content"}).text


    print("Título", titles, "\nLocalização", location, "\nLink", link, "\nConteudo", conteudo)
```

Example: I'm not getting anything under "conteudo" variable. I've tried to get different data from the Details Page, like the Price or number of Rooms but It always fail and I just get "None".

I'm searching an answer since yesterday afternoon, but I'm not getting where I'm failing. I manage to get the parameters on the upper pages without problems, but when I reach the listings detail page level, it just fails.

If someone could just point me what I'm doing wrong, I will be grateful. Thanks in advance for the time that you take to read my question.

Comment: Have you disabled javascript in browser and re-loaded page to see if content is retrieved dynamically from elsewhere?

Comment: I think that it's not a dynamic problem. I just found that if I try like this:

for div in soup.find_all('div', id='listing-content'):
    print(div.text)

it works...

But this:

 conteudo = anuncios_soup.find("div", {"id":"listing-content"}).text

Don't work!

I'm getting confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get correct page you need to set `User-Agent` http header.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


main_url = 'https://timetochoose.co.ao/?search-listings=true'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}


def print_info(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.select_one('#listing-content').get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))


soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(main_url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
for a in soup.select('a.listing-featured-image'):
    print(a['href'])
    print_info(a['href'])
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
https://timetochoose.co.ao/listings/loja-rua-rei-katiavala-luanda/
Avenida brasil , Rua katiavala
Maculusso
Loja com 90 metros quadrados
2 andares
1 wc
Frente a estrada
Arrendamento  mensal 500.000 kz Negociável
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://timetochoose.co.ao/listings/apertamento-t3-rua-cabral-montcada-maianga/
Apartamento T3 maianga
1  suíte com varanda
2 quartos com varanda
1 wc
1 sala comum grande
1 cozinha
Tanque de  agua
Predio limpo
Arrendamento 350.000  akz Negociável
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: thank you, your suggestion works well. Right now I'm still trying to get where I was failing. I have updated the user agent and I have made some more tests, and I have found that the problem on my code starts here: anuncios_response = requests.get(link) - when I print this it return 410, so of course everything next will fail.

Comment: @theprodigy83 yes, you need to specify headers in `anuncios_response = requests.get(link, headers=<headers here>)` to get correct response.

Comment: Ah, now I got it. I was missing to add the headers on the requests parameters.